# How do I install Ubuntu onto a Macbook running OSX without a CD or USB of Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, macosx, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro running OSX Mountain Lion presently. I downloaded the Desktop version of Ubuntu (12.04.2) which is a .iso application. I'm not amazing with computers, and am having extreme difficulty figuring out how to install Ubuntu, whether it's dual boot or a full install.

Can someone tell me how exactly I go about doing this?

-Brad

Comment: Basically you need to burn the .iso to a CD. Is there a reason why you specified "without a CD or USB"?

Answer (score 0):

You need netboot / PXE boot.

You need to setup a PXE boot server. Refer [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer) for the same.

Once you have the server, use [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot) to know how to use it to install ubuntu on your mac. This would require a network connection which will connect these two systems (no internet required).